# Tax not applied when performing backend membership renewal

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, taxes

We have a lot of different taxes on our implementation - doing a backend renewal does not apply the tax (however, this works when a NEW membership is created). Anyone have a fix? I tried searching the issue tracker but couldn't find anything about this.

Version: CiviCRM 4.6

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind - I was able to track it down - it was reported in version 4.6.5 and there appears to be a fix.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16950?jql=text%20~%20%22renewal%20taxes%22

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the previous post link was for the wrong issue - this is the correct one, which shown status is Fixed for Civi 4.7.31:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21485?jql=text%20~%20%22renewal%20taxes%22

I got it working - follow the links on the issue, click files to see the required code to be added.  Sales Tax was added on a backend renewal after applying the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This is a question and answer forum.  You've posted this as an answer but it looks more like a question.  It would be better to post it as a comment or ask a new question.